# OSX terminal broken after trying to install cisco packet tracer

Tags: bash, macos, macos-sierra

I tried to install cisco packet tracer on my mac. It was a sh script to install it. I ran it but not in su and it did some mess on my mac. After 1min i saw that my disk was full, since the script copied repertories everywhere. 
Now, when i launch my terminal, the commands i recently installed (npm, brew, cordova...) are not recognized anymore, and there is not my user name at the beginning of the line, there is

```
-bash-3.2$
```

At every launch of the terminal, i get this error on the top of it :

```
Last login: Wed Jan  4 17:04:13 on ttys000
-bash: /etc/profile: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: /etc/profile: line 1: `-e \n# System-wide .profile for sh(1)\n\nif [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then\neval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`\nfi\n\nif [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then\n[ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc\nfi\nPT7HOME=/Users/myusername/Documents/pt'
```

I deleted the folder /Users/myusername/Documents/pt, but it seems that this is where the error is coming from. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Use the Time Machine to revert the changes.

Comment: I suggest you talk to cisco and demand your money back.  Seriously though, cisco support should be contacted.

Comment: On the plus side, the only immediate damage to your `/etc/profile` seems to be the addition of `-e ` (or perhaps a literal string `-e \n`) to the top of the file. Remove that bit, up to `# System-wide .profile`, to take a big step closer to being fixed.

Comment: Actually, I take that back: the error message seems to indicate that all the newlines were converted by the installer to literal `\n` sequences. See my not-really-an-answer for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

The error message implies that your `/etc/profile`, which by default looks like

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
        eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
        [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

was intended to be modified by adding a single line to the bottom

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
        eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
        [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
PT7HOME=/Users/myusername/Documents/pt
```

However, *something* went wrong, and in addition to adding a few extra characters to the beginning of the file, the indentation was removed and the newlines were converted to literal `\n` sequences, resulting in the contents becoming a single line, perhaps

```
-e \n# System-wide .profile for sh(1)\n\nif [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then\neval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`\nfi\n\nif [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then\n[ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc\nfi\nPT7HOME=/Users/myusername/Documents/pt
```

Without further information, I would suggest that you *could* simply edit the file to look like the modified version above. However, @n.m.'s and @cdarke's suggestions should both be taken: restore from backup if possible, and contact user support to figure out what exactly may be wrong with the script.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. I finnaly made a clean install of my mac because i still had the error.